# How multiply 2 column of 2 different table in SQL.And store record 2 table column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have 2 table in SQL as labor and daily-record. In labor table I have column id,name,pay,perhourrate  and other table hour,daycost column now I want multiply 2 column as perhoureate*hour and store in cost

Comment: Could you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use MySQL and you don't know how to connect the database and grab the data and at the same time, you want to achive that with PHP coding, because I saw PHP tag blow the question. You need to explain yourself in detailed.

First of all, we create a connection between PHP and MySQL

```
$user = "root"; //database username
$pwd = "1234"; //database password
$host = "localhost"; //mysql server
$db = "dbname"; //database name

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd) or die("Connection Failed!".mysql_error()); //This line starts the connection
```

Secondly, grab the data

```
$resultPerhourrate = mysql_query("SELECT perhourrate FROM labor ORDER BY id");

while($getPerhourrate = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultPerhourrate)){ 
        $returnPerhourrate[] = $getPerhourrate['perhourrate'];

} 


$resultHour = mysql_query("SELECT hour FROM daily_record ORDER BY id");

while($getHour = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultHour)){ 
        $returnHour[] = $getHour['hour']; 
}
```

Now, you can calcule the cost for each item

```
$calculateCount = count($returnHour); //It takes the size of the array

for($i=0; $i<$calculateCount; $i=$i+1){
    $calculatedCost[$i] = $getPerhourrate*$getHour;
}
```

Also, you can store cost values which are ordered by id

```
for($i=0; $i<$calculateCount; $i=$i+1){
$add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO labor (cost) values('$calculatedCost[$i]' WHERE id='$getID[$İ])");
}
```

If you have already insert the data, you have to use UPDATE parameter with mysql_wuery.

Answer (score 0):

Consider there is an common column between the tables say `id` then you can `update-join` like

```
update tbl2 t2
set t2.daycost = t2.hour * t1.perhourrate
join tbl1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Can you tell me please
update tbl2 t2
set t2.daycost = t2.hour * t1.perhourrate
join tbl1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id;  

what is t2 ????